# Where is the body of stat function in fs node mdoule?

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm learning nodeJS and came across the node module `fs`

There is a line of code as follows:

```
export function stat(
  path: PathLike,
  callback: (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException | null, stats: Stats) => void
): void;
```

In my file where I use stat, I have the following code:

```
fs.stat(filepath, (err, stats) => {
  if (err) {
    res.statusCode = 404
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html")
    res.end(
      "<html><body><h1>Error 404: " + fileUrl + " not found</h1></body></html>"
    )
    return
  }
})
```

I am supplying the callback function but I want to know where is my function receiving the **err** and **stats** object from.

I am assuming there must be a function body of **stat** that calls the function I have defined and provides the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. `fs.stat()`'s code invokes your callback when it has the result you need. This is a very common nodejs / Javascript pattern.

The code in `fs` is mostly native operating system code rather than Javascript code. It's internal to nodejs and its purpose is to access your machine's file system. So using your debugger to step into it may be confusing.

A remark on another aspect of your code: nodejs / express makes it easy to do 404 errors from within express functions. If you call `next()` with a parameter, express reports an error to the web site visitor or API user. Something like this:

```js
const createError = require('http-errors')
 ...
       fs.stat(filepath, (err, stats) => {
         if (err) return next(createError(404, fileUrl + ' not found'))
         ...
       })
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate a unique ID for error, return it in your response.

Log the error(err) object(console, logger, etc..) with this generated ID to follow the case. (error objects in responses are ugly and unveil you call stack or internals.) In the error object, you will find details as possible.